# Low battery detection circuit that can tell if temporary voltage dip or actual low battery

Tags: batteries, analog, low-power, detection

I am currently using a schmitt trigger to turn off power to non essential circuits when the battery voltage dips below a certain threshold.

The problem with this circuit is that it is dumb, i.e., it cannot tell the difference between a temporary voltage drop across the battery due to a high current load being switched on, and when the battery is actually low.

What kind of analog circuit can I add to differentiate between these two events?

Edit: I have a 12V LA battery that dips to around 8V for approx. 1 sec when I turn on a high current load.

Comment: Why do you insist on it being an analog circuit? How about throwing a tiny microcontroller and some simple software at it?

Comment: Micrcontrollers are expensive when you include components such as the crystal, and the cost to create and maintain the software.

Comment: Dan, this is a repeated discussion here on Electronics.SE. Olin will come and say you have to use a PIC10F220 :-). Most of the times he's right. In software you can construct filters which are hard to do in hardware, and the PIC10F220 doesn't need a crystal. All it needs is a decoupling capacitor.

Comment: I think what we need here is an 8 pin microcontoller programmed to act like a 555 timer, then configure it as monoflop ;o)

Comment: Why are you all still talking about microcontrollers? This is a basic low pass filter application.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a low pass filter.

A temporary dip is a high frequency event, while a real low battery is a low frequency event. If you pass this signal through a low pass filter, it will remove the high frequency events, and allow the low frequency one to pass.

[image: Low pass filter]

Increasing the value of the capacitor and resistor increases the time constant, thus decreasing the frequency threshold.

Answer (score 4):

**Filter with fast reset:**

Assuming

- CMOS Schmitt
- Schmitt sees high = OK input

Feed Schmitt input via a resistor.
 Add capacitor from Schmitt input to ground.
 Optional - add diode across resistor, Cathode to Schmitt, Anode to voltage source (ie diode "arrow" points at Schmitt).

Diode adds "fast recovery" which simple RC lacks. If Vin is low 51% + of time for periods < RC time constant a simple RC will slowly discharge and trip. The diode "resets" the capacitor rapidly and means dropouts of ~= t = RC+ are needed to trigger output.

[image]

If Schmitt is already fed by a resistor divider just add cap + diode to input resistor.

When input goes high cap charges via diode to Vdiode < Vmax then cap tops up via Rin.

When input blips low cap starts to discharge via Rin with time constant R x C.

If Vin restores high then diode will allow charging faster than if just via Rin.

Time constant = Rin x Capacitor value.

eg if C=0.1 uF, R=10k. Tc = R.C = 10,000 x 10^-7 = 1mS = not long.
 100k , 1 uF = 0.1s.
 100k, 10 uF = 1 s
 etc.
Cap best to be NOT electrolytic due to leakage but depends on cap and brand.

Actual delay till triggering depends on how far Vin is above Vtrip but 1+ timje constant usual.

As always, component types and an actual circuit diagram would help.

Comment: Wouldn't the diode just bypass R1?

Comment: @Dan - Yes - but only when Vin >= Vcap + Vdiode - that's the reason for having it. When the occasional dip lowers Vcap and then Vin restores to full value the diode gets Vcap back there faster. On a real low the diode is reverse biased and stays that way until trip point is reached.